# Ruby Update Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

The update function is working within my ruby console as shown below, but the updates aren't being reflected in the database for this particular user.

For all other users it works perfectly, and using update_all works, but also updates all other users. Any idea why?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :002 > User.update(51, :introduction => "testupdate")
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 51]]
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "introduction" = 'testupdate', "updated_at" = '2011-09-13 18:53:25.896711' WHERE "users"."id" = 51

 => #<User id: 51, email: "example@email.com", introduction: "testupdate", created_at: "2011-09-13 18:45:18", updated_at: "2011-09-13 18:53:25">
```

FYI The user I'm trying to update is the only user created manually via log-in, the others are created as dummy accounts via seeds.rb

Comment: Have you checked for failing validations?

Comment: yes, I'm using Devise for authentication and tried removing all validations. Still stumped.

Comment: wow. nevermind - I accidentally had an after_save in the User model that was actually causing a validation failure. Oops!

Comment: Could you write an answer and accept it to close your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally had an after_save in the User model that was actually causing a validation failure.  Thanks @meagar